# Ionic emulate - Erro ao rodar em máquina com processador AMD

Tags: android, ionic, emulador

Quando tento dar o `ionic emulate android` dá o seguinte erro:

> emulator:
>   Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
>   emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>
> CPU acceleration status: Androi
>   d Emula
>   tor re
>   quire
>   s an In
>   tel pr
>   ocesso
>   r with
>    VT-x
>   and NX
>    support
>   .  Your CPU: 'AuthenticAMD'

Então, pesquisei sobre o erro e tentei algumas soluções, como as sugeridas [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration), mas não consegui resolver.

Tentei rodar um app simples com o Android Studio pra ver se o problema não era exclusivo do ionic e acabei esbarrando no mesmo erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso uma máquina Windows 7 Professional SP1 com processador AMD 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando achei essa solução:

1. Vá em painel de controle
2. Programas e Recursos
3. Ativar ou desativar recursos do Windows
4. Desmarque a opção "Hyper-V" na janela que se abrir
5. Reinicie o computador

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911176/haxm-installation-fails-claiming-vt-x-not-present

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Fiz como sugeriu só que a opção "Hyper-V" não aparece. Então lendo os comentários do link que vc sugeriu, vi que essa solução é pra uma versão específica do windows 8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911176/haxm-installation-fails-claiming-vt-x-not-present#comment50009785_28949355